# Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: FluxStore has not overridden FluxStore.__onDispatch(), which is required

Tags: reactjs, store, flux

This is the code for my store:

```
var Store = require("flux/utils").Store;
var ApiUtil = require("../util/api_util");
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/dispatcher');
var _users = ApiUtil.getUsers() || [];
var CHANGE_EVENT = "change";
var UserStore = new Store(AppDispatcher);

UserStore._onDispatch = function(payload){
    switch(payload.actionType){
        case UserConstants.USERS_RECEIVED:
            console.log(payload);
            UserStore.changed();
            break;
    }
};
```

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title (viz. "Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: FluxStore has not overridden FluxStore.__onDispatch(), which is required") when an ApiActions method hits this:

```
AppDispatcher.dispatch({
    actionType: UserConstants.USERS_RECEIVED,
    users: users
});
```

I have added the FluxStore overwrite for the _onDispatch method as requested, but am still getting the error. Am I overwriting it incorrectly?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

FluxStore.__onDispatch() has two __

And you have defined it as UserStore._onDispatch instead of UserStore.__onDispatch